# How to solve automatic logging out in chrome browser of android 8 oreo?

Tags: php, android, codeigniter

I had ran into a strange problem.

If i login to my website, and navigate to other pages its not logging out.
If i login and navigate to any other page in chrome browser of android 8 oreo, it is logging out.
Automatically session is destroying in android 8.
I am not able to understand what is happening

Help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: I think its browser issue, Uninstall  or updated latest version.

Comment: If you are using cookies, then what is the age of the cookie? or if you are using tokens then are you storing them properly (in say Localstorage)?

Comment: Did you set the session save path on codeigniter config.php don't leave it null https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences